# Fixed size DIV exceeding

Tags: html, css

a content inside div exceeding the fixed size which is decided by css.

```html
<style>
  #fixeddiv {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
</style>

<div id="fixeddiv">
  
  <div id="M775568ScriptRootC1273665"></div>
<script src="https://jsc.adskeeper.co.uk/c/r/creditkarma.gq.1253664.js" async>
</script>
</div>
```

The content inside fixeddiv should be fixed between 300px height and 700px width but it exceeding it and position of the content displaying outside of fixed size.

Edited: Child DIV contain responsive native ad and i am trying to fix the position with parent DIV because i do not make modification inside the ad copy due to advertising network policy.

Comment: what is the type of this content ? is it text or image or something else ?

Comment: @ArafatAhmed advertising. In another DIV it is a a JavaScript which load advertising

Comment: make its position relative

Comment: @ArafatAhmed content still exceeding `height` . i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>

#fixeddiv { 
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 700px; 
    width:100%;       
    height:100%;
}
  #someotherdiv {
    height:100%;
  }
</style>

<div id="fixeddiv">
<div id="someotherdiv"> contents </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
#fixeddiv > div{
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

It really depends on the content inside the fixed div. You can also add `overflow:hidden` so the child content wont overflow the fixed div boundaries

Comment: it still exceeding the `max-height` and the content of right side getting moved below instead of getting fit in it.

Comment: most probably, you have absolute/forced flow positioning inside the children of the ad content. It's a bit hard to have a proper answer without knowing the css/structure inside

Answer (score 1):

Apply `width`/`height` values to `image` not container.

```css
#fixeddiv {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  border: 20px solid;
}

img {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixeddiv">
  <img src="https://pixy.org/src/20/201310.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: It not a normal image. it an advertisement and i have no access to edit the code of advertisement.

Comment: @shanmugapradeep Yes, I have read that but just apply this to the container in which image will be shown. Like, here image will be shown in `img` tag, so I applied it on that.